# Promesas en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promesas, ecmascript-6

tengo un problema con el asincronismo...

estoy intentando crear un servicio en angular que me entregue los datos de un excel en json. esto lo estoy realizando con una librería y funciona bien.
mi problema es que llamarlo como servicio lo dejo dentro de una promesa pero dentro del flujo existe un proceso que tarda un poco y me retorna los datos en undefined.

```js
prueba(evt:any){
  var data:any;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');

    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

//esta es la parte que tarda y es justo lo que necesito
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {

      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
/*esta data es el dato que necesito*/
      data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 2}));
    }

   if(resolve) {
     resolve(data);
   } else {
      reject('Failure!');
   }
  });
}
```

Dentro de mi lógica creo que necesito dejar una promesa dentro de otra y no he logrado encontrar información al respecto.
Espero que me puedan ayudar. de todas formas agradezco su tiempo.

---

agradezco tu respuesta. Realice algunos cambios en mi código basado en tu respuesta pero no logré que funcionara como corresponde. actualmente para salir del problema estoy usando un timeOut pero necesito que quede como corresponde, a continuación te envío el estado actual de mi código. –

```
    onFileChange(evt: any) : any {
  return new Promise(result=>{
    // alert("bla");
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
      this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 2}));

    };
    setTimeout(() => {
            result(this.data);
          }, 1000);

             reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);




  });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ese caso puedes usar Async/Await.

Await te permite detener el flujo de ejecución hasta que una promise sea resuelta y una vez resuelta te devuelve el resultado de dicha promise, es decir lo que devuelvas con la función resolve de dicha promise. Ten en cuenta que para usar la palabra clave await deberás declarar dicha función con la palabra clave async.

```
async prueba(evt:any){
  var data:any;
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');

    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

//esta es la parte que tarda y es justo lo que necesito
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {

      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
/*esta data es el dato que necesito*/
      data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 2}));

      resolve(data);
    }

   if(resolve) {
     resolve(data);
   } else {
      reject('Failure!');
   }
  });
}
```

Comment: hola, agradezco tu respuesta. Realice algunos cambios en mi código basado en tu respuesta pero no logré que funcionara como corresponde. actualmente para salir del problema estoy usando un timeOut pero necesito que quede como corresponde, a continuación te envío el estado actual de mi código.